# How to insert multiple rows of a HTML table in my database

Tags: html, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I am using Asp.Net Core to create a software but I am getting an error from the backend web api (from CreateUpdate function) of my application when I am trying to insert multiple rows from the HTML table I have created from the frontend.
Can someone please help to fix this error in the Foreach Loop ?

```
    public void CreateUpdate(OrderVm orderVm)
    {
        Order oOrder = new Order();
        oOrder.FinalTotal = orderVm.FinalTotal;
        oOrder.OrderDate = DateTime.Now.ToString();
        oOrder.OrderDateTime = DateTime.Now;
        oOrder.OrderNumber = String.Format("{0:hhddmmssmmmyyyy}", DateTime.Now);
        oOrder.Description = "Hello there";
        _context.Orders.Add(oOrder);
        _context.SaveChanges();

        int orderId = oOrder.OrderId;

        foreach (var item in orderVm.OrderDetails)
        {
            OrderDetail objOrderDetail = new OrderDetail();
            objOrderDetail.OrderId = orderId;
            objOrderDetail.ItemId = item.ItemId;
            objOrderDetail.ReservationId = item.ReservationId;
            objOrderDetail.SubTotal = item.SubTotal;
            objOrderDetail.UnitPrice = item.UnitPrice;
            objOrderDetail.Quantity = item.Quantity;
            _context.OrderDetails.Add(objOrderDetail);
            _context.SaveChanges();

        }
    }
```

```js
    const AddToChartTable = () => {
        var tblItemList = $("#tblItemsList");
        var unitPrice = $("#txtUnitPrice").val();
        var qty = $("#txtQuantity").val();
        var itemId = $("#txtItemId").val();
        var itemName = $("#txtItemName option:selected").text();
        var subtotal = (unitPrice * qty);

        var itemList = "<tr><td hidden>" + itemId +
            "</td><td>" + itemName +
            "</td><td>" + parseFloat(unitPrice).toFixed(2) +
            "</td><td>" + parseFloat(qty).toFixed(2) +
            "</td><td>" + parseFloat(subtotal).toFixed(2) +
            "</td><td> <input type = 'button' value = 'Remove' name = 'Cancel' class='btn btn-      danger' onclick = 'CancelItem(this)' /> </tr ></tr > ";

        tblItemList.append(itemList);
        //FinalItemTotal();
        ResetItem();
    }

 const FinalPayment = () => {
        var objOrderVM = {};
        var OrderDetails = new Array();
        objOrderVM.ReservationId = $("#txtOrderDetailId").val();
        objOrderVM.ItemId = $("#txtItemId").val();
        objOrderVM.FinalTotal = $("#txtFinalTotal").val();
        //console.log(objOrderVM.FinalTotal);
        $("#tblItemsList").find("tr:gt(0)").each(function () {
            var OrderDetailVM = {};
            OrderDetailVM.SubTotal = parseFloat($(this).find("td:eq(4)").text());
            OrderDetailVM.ItemId = parseFloat($(this).find("td:eq(0)").text());
            OrderDetailVM.UnitPrice = parseFloat($(this).find("td:eq(2)").text());
            OrderDetailVM.Qty = parseFloat($(this).find("td:eq(3)").text());

            OrderDetails.push(OrderDetailVM);
        });

        objOrderVM.OrderDetails = OrderDetails;

        $.ajax({
            async: true,
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'JSON',
            contentType: 'application/json, charset=utf-8',
            data: JSON.stringify(objOrderVM),
            url: '/OrderDetails/AddUpdateOrderDetail',
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("Impossible to get data from the database");
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Which error?  Show full exception details including call stack.

Comment: System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'